# Rename files to remove ";" from all filenames containing it in bash

Tags: bash, shell-script

I know how to replace a set of characters in filenames. E.g

```
for i in *example_text* ;
do
    mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/example_text//'`"
done
```

How do I do so if a part of the filename is ";" (between quotes). I get an error whenever I try to run:

```
for i in *;* ;
do
    mv "$i" "`echo $i | sed 's/;//'`"
done
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 18):

While using `mv` in a loop will work, I suggest to use perl `rename` instead (it might be installed as `perl-rename` or `prename`, depending on your operating system).
It is a tool made exactly for your purpose and is very likely to be installed on your system already.

`rename 's/;//g' ./*` will do the trick,
you can review what would be done with a dry-run first: `rename -v -n 's/;//g' ./*`

Comment: Thanks for the edits Stéphane :-)

Answer (score 13):

Escape the semicolon, it's a special character for the shell.

```
for i in *\;*
# or
for i in *';'*
```

If you're using `bash`, parameter expansion is much faster than shelling out to `sed`.

```
for f in *';'* ; do
    mv -- "$f" "${f//;/}"
done
```

Note that it can overwrite a file if it already exists. Use `mv -n` or check for existence with `test -e`.